# How to provide custom str method also for String?

Tags: string, rust

I made a new trait method for str type that iterating Unicode graphemes. It works like `lines()` method of str.

```rust
struct BreakGraphemes<'a> {
    slice: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for BreakGraphemes<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        // Some long codes...
        ...

        Some(&self.slice[..next_idx])
    }
}

trait Segmentation {
    fn break_graphemes(&self) -> BreakGraphemes;
}

impl Segmentation for &str {
    fn break_graphemes(&self) -> BreakGraphemes {
        BreakGraphemes { slice: self }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "Hello, ☝";
    for grapheme in s.break_graphemes() {
        println!("{}", grapheme.len());
    }
}
```

But when I tried for String type, compiler claims an error.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hello, ☝");
    for grapheme in s.break_graphemes() {
        println!("{}", grapheme.len());
    }
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `break_graphemes` found for struct `std::string::String` in the current scope
```

But according to rust standard library documentation(https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref-methods), there are many of methods for str can be used also String type because String implements Deref trait to str.

How can i achieve this feature for my method? Or is it impossible?

Comment: `str` and `&str` are different types.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. I'm pretty sure just changing `&str` to `str` fixes your problem but I can't be bothered to try to guess at all the `...`s that I would have to change to verify it.

Comment: @trentcl The real implementation is long and messy. Anyway it works. Thanks!

Comment: Change it to `impl Segmentation for str` (without the reference). This should do the trick. Currently you have a double indirection; because it is implemented for `&str` and the method accepts `&self`, the receiver type is `&&str`. This does not work well with auto-`Deref`.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use the [`unicode-segmentation`](https://docs.rs/unicode-segmentation/1.6) crate? It already provides an iterator over graphemes, for example: `"a̐éö̲\r\n".graphemes(true).collect::<Vec<&str>>()`